# error is coming while compiling cpp file with linaro toolchain

Tags: c++

I am trying to cross-compile openmcu-ru with linaro toolchain ,I am getting error in compiling conference.cxx file
It compiled correctly in ubuntu using gcc toolchain 
but getting error with linaro toolchain

Following is error

> conference.cxx:1503:6: error: prototype for 'void
>   ConferenceMember::Dial(PBoolean)' does not match any in class
>   'ConferenceMember'  void ConferenceMember::Dial(BOOL _autoDial)

Following is code

```
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 #define BOOL PBoolean

BOOL autoDial   ;                
    void ConferenceMember::Dial()
    {              
     Dial(autoDial);
    } 

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    void ConferenceMember::Dial(BOOL _autoDial)  // **Line no. 1503**
    {                                        
      if(IsSystem())                       
        return;
      PWaitAndSignal m(dialMutex);
      autoDial = _autoDial;                                                             
      if((autoDial && (OpenMCU::Current().autoDialDelay < 20)) || IsOnline())
        return;                           
      MCUH323EndPoint & ep = OpenMCU::Current().GetEndpoint();
      if(dialToken != "" && ep.HasConnection(dialToken))
        return;                               
      dialToken = ep.Invite(conference->GetNumber(), GetName());
    }
```

Regards

Comment: Where is `ConferenceMember` declaration?

Answer (score 0):

got the solution 
changing BOOL to int in line 1503